# Как прочитать свойство e.target.value у инпута в котором есть debounce функция?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook

Такая ситуация. В инпуте в событии onChange есть useDebounce первым аргументом которого является функция onSearchChange.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В функции onSearchChange я пытаюсь достать e.target.value, но выходит ошибка. Как исправить? Как достать вводимый value?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой useDebounce.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получаете ли вы вообще event?

Comment: Можете до  input.value  достучатся ref. Он вернёт объект с ключём current вроде.